# Deep link doesn't work if it's a redirect url

Tags: vue.js, deep-linking, capacitor

I'm using Capacitor (with VueJS), my deep link is working correctly, but it doesn't work if it's a redirect URL.

I want to use oauth2 to connect to Facebook. When I enter my Facebook login/password, Facebook redirects me to my server API "https://myapi.com/mydeeplink", but my app doesn't trigger the deep link (it doesn't ask me if I want to open this URL with my app).

I know this is because of the redirect URL, because it's working if I go manually to "https://myapi.com/mydeeplink" in Google Chrome.

The question is: Is it possible to trigger the deep link if it's a redirected URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OKAY It seems I've found the answer!

With Capacitor we have to use Browser Plugin.

When i will click on my Facebook button to login i will call the Browser.open to open the link in a way that AppUrlOpen will be triggered everytime (even if it's redirect url)

```
    async LoginWithFacebook() {
      await this.$browser.open({ url: this.$api_addr + 'auth/facebook' });
    },
```

..i login with facebook..
..my server redirect me to app://mydomain/myroute?myquery=param..

then i can catch the deeplink with: App.addListener('appUrlOpen' ..)

```
  App.addListener('appUrlOpen', function (data) {
    const url = "area://mydomain/myroute"
    let slug = data.url.split(url).pop();

    if (data.url.startsWith(url)) { // if it's the good url I redirect to my app
      this.$router.router(`/${slug ? slug : ""}`);
    }
  });
```

Care! To make it works you need association file explained here:
"https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links", ITS IS MANDATORY!!

Then you have to add this to your Mani

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="mydomain" />
            </intent-filter>
```

DONE

Comment: can you please help by giving file name in which file you have added listener code and in which xml?
because I am facing same issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: look at this: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links

Comment: hey @TheoCerutti care to explain why catching the url and then just using the router? I am facing the same issue on Android. My back end deeplinks me with http://example.com?code="mytoken" this is a re-direct that happen with a 302 on the backend but once the page is in the browser it's never catched by Android and never opens my app

Comment: Sorry I don't know, it's been a long time so I don't really remember :'(